# Angularjs - How to create forms so that fields can get mapped back to stripes framework actions

Tags: java, angularjs, stripes, restangular

I am using angularjs, restangular and the java stripes framework in my project.

I want my form to pass up params such that stripes will map the params back to the objects in my action.

My stripes action works and looks like

```
@DefaultHandler
public Resolution allUsers(){....}

private User newUser;
//Getter and setter  
public Resolution createUser()
{
    //persist the user
}
```

My very simple angularjs

```
var usrs = Restangular.all('User.action');
usrs.getList().then(function(users){
    $scope.users = users;
});

$scope.newUser = {};

$scope.createUser = function(){
    usrs.post('ajax/UserAjax.action?', $scope.newUser).then(
        function(data)
        {
            $scope.users.push(data);
        }
    );
};
```

And my form

```
<form ng-submit="createUser()" >
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="newUser.createUser" name="newUser.createUser" ng-init="newUser.createUser=''" value="{{newUser.createUser}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="newUser.login" ng-model="newUser.login"/>
    <input type="text" name="newUser.password" ng-model="newUser.password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

My form will post and send up the params. But it sends up login=xxx and password=xxx. And so the action gets a null newUser. I want to pass up newUser.login=xxx and newUser.password=xxx so that stripes will do the mapping.

I can get the following to work, but I don't like it:

```
$scope.createUser = function(){
    usrs.post('ajax/UserAjax.action?', {createUser:'','newUser.login':$scope.newUser.login,'newUser.password':$scope.newUser.password})).then(
        function(data)
        {
            $scope.users.push(data);
        }
    );
};
```

I've also tried things like

```
<input type="text" name="newUser.newUser.login" ng-model="newUser.newUser.login"/>
<input type="text" name="newUser.'newUser.login'" ng-model="newUser.'newUser.login'"/>
```

How do I get angularjs/restangular to pass up params with '.' in the names?

Comment: did you try ng-model='newUser["newUser.login"]' /> ??

Comment: I just found out that I could reference properties that way. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="newUser[newUser.login]" ng-model="newUser[newUser.login]"/>
```